# How to create a download attribute in html

Tags: html

So I have a website I'm working where you click a link and you can download a pdf file.
The thing is I can't figure out how to do that. I tried using `a href = "#" download = "my-pdf-file"` but that didn't work and I also tried `a download = "my-pdf-file"` but that didn't work I tried replacing `my-pdf-file` with the path to it but it wouldn't work cause the file exists only on my pc.

Comment: Href should point to the file you are trying to download. Setting a value to the download attribute only overrides the name that the file should be downloaded as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload a file on google drive or mediafire, and set code up like:

```
<a href="item link here" download>Text here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To download from link mention

> download

attribute

```
<a href="LINK_TO_DOWNLOAD" download>Download</a>
```